Difference between 頁 and ページ
What is the difference (historical or otherwise) in the use of  頁 and ページ to describe a page number or the number of pages of a work?

Short answer: You can basically stick to the katakana ページ in modern Japanese.
Long answer:
頁 is a kanji that originally meant "head" in Chinese. From Wiktionary:

頁
頁 and 首 (OC *hljuʔ, *hljus) were originally the same pictographic character with the same meaning of “head”, and the graphical difference was that 頁 also included the body in addition to the head of the person.
頁 was later used as an alternative popular form of 葉 (“leaf; page”) to mean “sheet; page (of paper)”, which is its main meaning today.
The original sense of “head” is preserved in the radical 頁, which is used in characters such as 頭 (“head”) and 頸 (“neck”).

Also in Japanese, the kanji 頁 almost always means "page" today. However, only in Japanese, it also gained the kun-reading of "ページ"!
The usual kun-readings are Japanese native pronunciations applied to kanji. However, around the 1900s, a new type of kun-reading where English-based pronunciations are assigned to kanji became popular (see 義訓 in Wikipedia).
Most of these were more of wordplays and did not become established as formal Japanese. However, a few words, including 麦酒【ビール】 (beer) and 白金【プラチナ】 (platinum), became relatively established and were included in some dictionaries.
頁【ページ】 is one of them. It is still widely recognized by adults as the kanji for "page", but its usage has been constantly declining. Today, there may be some elderly novelists who prefer this kanji, and modern musicians may choose it to add some nostalgic flavor to their lyrics. However, there is almost no need for the general public to use it today. It is sufficient to understand its meaning when you read old books.

Very nice! Many thanks for such a careful answer.
